# Android Unit Test : how to clear SharedPreferences

Tags: android, unit-testing, sharedpreferences, android-testing

I am trying to clear all SharedPreferences added during my tests. I already read some posts and the official documentation ([SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear%28%29)). But when I start my application after the unit tests were run, I still found test values.

So, in the [AndroidTestCase.tearDown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html#tearDown%28%29), I make this :

```java
public class PrivateStorageUtilsTest extends AndroidTestCase {

private static final String KEY_SP_PACKAGE = "PrivateStorageUtilsTest";

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        // Clear everything in the SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext()
            .getSharedPreferences(KEY_SP_PACKAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // Clear everything in the SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().
            getSharedPreferences(KEY_SP_PACKAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Every other questions I found on SO was about adding `commit()` after the `clear()`, which I already done here.

**EDIT 1** Adding `setUp()` method

**EDIT 2** Providing extended class

Comment: are you using the same context to wrinte and clear the SharedPreferences?

Comment: the Context is the one provided by AndroidTestCase class. Also, when I launch my application, I still call `getContext()`. I can provide you the `setUp()` method of my unit tests if you want to.

Comment: yes probably it is better. Are you aware that when you run tests a different apk is update on the device test?

Comment: the setUp() method is added. And no, I was not aware of this fact. So, it really strange to still have to test values if it's not the same APK, isn't it ?

Comment: What class are you extending?

Comment: `public class PrivateStorageUtilsTest extends AndroidTestCase { ... }`

Comment: try extending `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, and use `getIntestrumentation().getTargetContext()` to retrieve the context of your application

Comment: seems to work :) thank you. Can you write it down in an answer that I will accept, and also give me some details on "why does it work this way ?" please ? ^^ I really don't understand how it changes the way of deleting the shared preferences content.

Comment: Do you want to clear the sharedpreferences your application wrote?

Comment: No I didn't want. But I want to delete the modification I done before. I understand why your way is a better one. However, I don't understand why mine *writes* but never *deletes*

Comment: I can not see where do you wrote it

Comment: In the tests (not showed in my snippet), where I was using getContext().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33919/discussion-between-mithrop-and-blackbelt)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should extend [`ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html) and use `getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()` to get the context for the target application being instrumented (under test)

Answer (score 21):

If you are using `ActivityTestRule` from [Espresso](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/index.html), try this:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule =
    new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class) {
        @Override
        protected void beforeActivityLaunched() {
            clearSharedPrefs(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
            super.beforeActivityLaunched();
        }
    };
```

With a slightly modified version of stevo.mit's `clearSharedPrefs`:

```
private static final String KEY_SP_PACKAGE = "PrivateStorageUtilsTest";

/**
* Clears everything in the SharedPreferences
*/
private void clearSharedPrefs(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = 
        context.getSharedPreferences(KEY_SP_PACKAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: One addition: Since your `clearSharedPrefs() method is independent of the test class, you should move it to helper class and make public and static so you can reuse it.

Answer (score 4):

I run your method with **AndroidJUnit4** and it works perfect when it is called as @Before and @After.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MyBusStopsTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MyBusStopsActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
            MyBusStopsActivity.class);

    @Before
    @After
    public void cleanSheredPrefs(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getSharedPreferences(MyBusStopsActivity.FAV_LIST, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Test
    public void showChooseBusStopActivityOnFABClick() {
        onView(withId(R.id.fab)).perform(click());
        onView(withChild(withId(R.id.choose_bus_button))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
 }
```

Comment: For me, this only works when using `@BeforeClass`, instead of `@Before`

Answer (score 3):

You test class should extend [`InstrumentationTestCase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html).

And you should use `getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()`.

If you need to manipulate **activity** directly, then your test class should extend [`ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html).

So your test case should look like this:

```
public class PrivateStorageUtilsTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

private static final String KEY_SP_PACKAGE = "PrivateStorageUtilsTest";

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        clearSharedPrefs();
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        clearSharedPrefs();
    }

    /**
     * Clears everything in the SharedPreferences
     */
    private void clearSharedPrefs() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().
             getSharedPreferences(KEY_SP_PACKAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```